# Xdebug, Docker and VSCode on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am looking for some guidance on setting up Xdebug with Docker and VSCode on Windows 10. My docker settings are as follows, but I always get 'EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9000' and never get any output from Xdebug from inside VSCode!

The project is Laravel based.

**.vscode\launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug on Docker App",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            // "pathMappings": {
            //     "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "C:\\development\\inventory-service\\"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

**dockerfile**

```
# Create and build composer dependencies
FROM composer:2.0 AS vendor

COPY database/ database/

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist

# Create and build application
FROM php:8.0-apache

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf \
    && sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete

# Install Xdebug
# RUN pecl install -f xdebug
# RUN echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini;
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "\n\
    xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.150.1 \n\
    xdebug.default_enable = 1 \n\
    xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 \n\
    xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0 \n\
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1 \n\
    xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp" \n\
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000 \n\
    xdebug.remote_log = /var/www/html/xdebug.log \n\
    " >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-xdebug.ini

# Copy the scheduler script into the image
COPY scheduler.sh /usr/local/bin/scheduler
COPY service.sh /usr/local/bin/service
# Set permissions on image folders
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers \
    && chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/scheduler \
    && chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/service

# Copy the application into the image
COPY --from=vendor /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor/
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set permissions on image folders
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

I've gone through a number of posts online to set this up but I always seem to have the same issue of port usage and/or no debug data (despite VSCode running the debugger).

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: 1) `ports:       - "8007:80"      - "9000:9000"` -- this is definitely wrong. A common mistake: it's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. VSCode cannot listen on already occupied (by Docker) port. 2) The IP -- it has to be the IP of the host, for Docker it's common to use `host.docker.internal` here (may require some extra steps if host OS is Linux)

Comment: 3) What is Xdebug version? if it's v3 .. then config is wrong -- v3 uses different parameter names and v2 params (that you have) do nothing in v3. If it's v3 then go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: @LazyOne I am using xdebug 3.1.0
The port mapping 8007:80 has always worked, the 9000:9000 was for the Xdebug setup!

Comment: @LazyOne - thanks I will try host.docker.internal again and check params for this version of Xdebug...

Comment: *"I am using xdebug 3.1.0 The port mapping 8007:80 has always worked, the 9000:9000 was for the Xdebug setup!"* Yes -- I forgot to mention that it's only the `- "9000:9000"` part that is wrong.  The website port is OK of course.

Comment: @LazyOne - perfect, up and running - thanks for your help :D

Comment: Post your config/solution as an answer then -- will help other users in a similar situation. You can accept your own answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so there was 1 file I needed to update (dockerfile) and I needed to create a new file (.vscode\launch.json).

Add the following to dockerfile (port number used by Xdebug is 9003)

```
# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "\n\
    xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal \n\
    xdebug.mode=debug \n\
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes \n\
    xdebug.discover_client_host=0 \n\
    xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp" \n\
    xdebug.client_port=9003 \n\
    xdebug.log = /var/www/html/xdebug.log \n\
    " >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-xdebug.ini
```

And then create or update your .vscode\launch.json (pathMappings: path on Docker then local path to your code folder)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug on Docker App",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "C:\\development\\inventory-service\\"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

...then rebuild your docker instance.

**Debugging in browser:**

From VSCode, select file for debugging, add break points where needed, then hit F5 to start debugging session. Then go to the page you are debugging, locally, from your web browser.

**Debugging artisan commands via console:**

From VSCode, select file for debugging, add break points where needed, then hit F5 to start debugging session. Then run the console command from the command line directly (in the normal manner) on the docker instance (choose the CLI from docker desktop for the relevant container/service).

I believe there is a way to test console from your VSCode terminal, but it never worked for me!